# Reading a struct from a read only memory

Tags: c++, embedded, constants, volatile

I'm working on a embedded system, where some calibration data is stored in the flash memory. The calibration data is stored in a struct which is placed in a special section that the linker knows to place in the flash:

```
struct data_block {
    calibration_data mData;
    uint16_t mCheckSum;
};

//Define to compile the fixed flash location for image data
const data_block __attribute__((section (".caldata"))) gCalibrationData{};
```

where `calibration_data` is another POD struct which contains the actual values.

The problem is that if I now simply write the following:

```
const data_block data{gCalibrationData};

if (CheckSum(&(data.mData)) == data.mCheckSum) {
    //do stuff
} else {
    //Error
}
```

this always goes to the error branch, even though the actual checksum in flash is absolutely correct (writing this a bit differently makes it work, see below).

This is of course understandable: the compiler sees a const global object, which is default-initialized, so it knows all the values, so I guess it actually optimizes out the whole `if` (if I debug-printf data via a `uint16_t *`, I actually get the correct values).

The way I think would be correct is to define

```
const volatile data_block __attribute__((section (".caldata"))) gCalibrationData{};
```

However, now I have the problem that I can't assign a volatile struct to non-volatile, i.e. `const data{gCalibrationData};` does not compile. The same problem also appears if I try to access through a `const volatile data_block *`.

There's at least two or three ways I can make this work, and I don't like any of them:

1. remove the `const` (and `volatile`) qualifier from `gCalibrationData`. However, this is a bit of a hack based on the compiler not being clever enough to guarantee that gCalibrationData is never touched in my program, and on the other hand, I'd like to keep to const qualifier, since trying to write to gCalibrationData by assigning is a hard fault.
2. access `gCalibrationData` via `const gCalibrationData * volatile pData` (yes, the volatile is exactly where I mean it). Accessing through a  pointer which is volatile forces the compiler to actually load the data. Again, this seems like a hack, since the pointer itself certainly isn't volatile.
3. give `data_block` and `calibration_data` an assignment operator taking `const volatile &`, and assign field by field in them. This seems to be correct from the language point of view, but then whenever `calibration_data` changes I need to edit the assignment operator by hand. Failing to do so will produce hard-to-detect bugs.

**My question:** what would be the correct way to read the calibration data? My ideal criteria would be:

- the global object itself is `const`, to catch unintended writes.
- no undefined behaviour
- access by assigning the struct directly to another struct
- or at least so that I'm not required to remember to assign each variable of primitive type in `calibration_data`, see option 3. above
- bonus points for thread-safety, although in my specific case only a single thread ever reads or writes the flash (all other "threads" are interrupts).

Comment: You may want to note why doing `const data_block data{gCalibrationData};` is important since it seems `if (CheckSum(&(gCalibrationData.mData)) == gCalibrationData.mCheckSum) {` should work.

Comment: @Dkrueger why do you think that would work? Anyway, I think my code would be quite brittle if it's broken by assigning to variable as an intermediate step.

Comment: To confirm, is the section `.caldata` definitely in ROM?

Comment: @edking yes, absolutely, confirmed in several ways.

Comment: @Timo In that case, I'm wondering whether you could solve your issues by abstracting the structure? If you made it private to some module and only allowed read access via a function, would you sufficiently protect it? Also, it seems counter-intuitive that you would compare two members of a `const` structure, since by the virtue that they're constant you would always know the answer to the comparison before the fact?

Comment: to correct your language the flash does not use structures from a programming language it stores bits/bytes, structures are a programming concept not a hardware concept.  Using structs across compile domains like this you should expect to have failures over time that will come and go.  Access the flash in a more reliable manner then if you feel the desire to fill a struct for that program then fill it in the program.

Comment: "no undefined behaviour", in that case you definitely cannot use a struct/union, etc.

Comment: @old_timer This data is only ever written or read to by exactly the same executable, since this is an embedded system with a fixed firmware, so I'm not crossing compile domains. Further, the C++ standard does admit concepts such POD, trivially_copyable, etc, which allow bit-by-bit copies of structs as long as certain rules are followed. So this should certainly be possible, and it is, as shown by Oliv's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to declare a buffer in a separate source file, to inform the linker of size of `data_block` and then define `gCalibrationData` to be a symbol whose value is the begining of this buffer:

**data_block.cpp**:

```
//no initialization performed here, just used to
//transmit to the linker the information of the size
//and alignment of data_block
extern "C"{//simpler name mangling
[[gnu::section(".caldata")]] volatile
aligned_storage<sizeof(data_block),alignof(data_block)> datablock_buffer;
}

//then we specify that gCalibrationData refers to this buffer
extern const volatile data_block
gCalibrationData [[gnu::alias("datablock_buffer")]];
```

Alternatively the definition of `gCalibrationData` symbol can be done via a linker script:

```
SECTIONS{
  .caldata : {
    gCalibrationData = . ;
    data_block.o(.caldata)
    }
  }
```

`gCalibrationData` is an alias to an `data_block_buffer`. This will not cause *undefined behavior* because such aliasing is permitted by the language: `data_block_buffer` [provides storage](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.memobj#intro.object-3) for `gCalibrationData`.

Semanticaly, the `extern` specifier is used to say that this declaration is not a definition of the value of `gCalibrationData`. Nevertheless the `alias` attribute is a definition of the symbol for the linker.

**data_block.hpp**

```
extern const volatile data_block gCalibrationData;

//and copy must be enabled for volatile:
struct data_block{
  /*...*/
  data_block(const data_block&) =default; 

  data_block& operator=(const data_block&) =default;

  data_block(const volatile data_block& other){
    //the const cast means: you are responsible not to 
    //perform this operation while performing a rom update.
    memcpy(this,const_cast<const data_block*>(&other);
    }

  data_block& operator=(const volatile data_block& other){
    memmove(this,const_cast<const data_block*>(&other);
    //or memcpy if you are sure a self assignment will never happen.
    return *this;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Sounds good in principle, but now that I tried it, what happens is that as I give the object non-default constructors, the default constructor is no longer a no-op, but attempts to zero-initialize the object at startup. That's a write to flash, and it's a hard fault. This also means that I was wrong about the reason why previously the startup was fine: since data_block itself was POD, the default construction was just leaving the object uninitialized.

Comment: It might be that the "proper" way is to do what your suggested constructor does, but in a free-standing `assign_volatile_pod` function, or something similar.

Comment: @Timo, What actualy happens is that static variable are always zero-initialized. The default constructor is not the responsible for that. I had not thought about that. So declaring it const or not const should not change the program semantic. But apparently by declaring it const you change the generated code. Probably the compiler think that const object are placed by the linker in a zeroed memory segment and that non-const object are not placed in zeroed memory region. So for these non const object it generates code to initialize to zero the memory. I update the answer.

Comment: I got around to trying this out again after quite a while. Your solution, with the following declaration for the variable itself, works:
    `const volatile __attribute__((section (".caldata"))) std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(data_block), alignof(data_block)> gCalibrationDataRaw{};
    const volatile data_block & gCalibrationData{*reinterpret_cast<const volatile data_block*>(&gCalibrationDataRaw)};`

Now, the reinterpret_cast still takes a memory where (at least during the current run) a `data_block` has never been constructed, so I'm not quite sure that this still isn't UB, though...

Comment: Anyway, if you edit that (or something even better which is certain to not have UB) in, I'll be happy to accept your answer :)

Comment: Oh, and I suppose it makes sense to restore the default constructors for the non-volatile case: `data_block(const data_block& other) = default;
 data_block(data_block&& other) = default;
 data_block& operator=(const data_block& other) = default;
 data_block& operator=(data_block&& other) = default;` ?

Comment: @Timo this is definitively not the way to go! The way to go is through a linker script, do you link with GNU/ld?

Comment: So that ordinary RAM copies of the struct use the ordinary assignment operators and constructors, avoiding the `std::copy`

Comment: yes, I do? What do you mean? The struct is placed here with the `__attribute__((section (".caldata")))`, and the section is indeed defined and placed in the linker script.

Comment: I mean, I could just reserve a raw binary block in the linker script, and then build a pointer to it at runtime, but then I need to know the size of `data_block` in the linker script.

Comment: You should just define a symbol `gcalibration_data = .caldata` in the linker script and just declare `extern "C" const volatile data_block gcalibration_data` in the source file.

Comment: But then how does the linker know the size of `data_block`? And what's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Because as you say this is a hackery, and it is probably undefined behavior. You can define a `[[gnu:section(".caldata")]] unsigned char cal_buffer[sizeof(data_block)];` in a source file. This way the linker will know the size of data_block. From a language point of view there will be no aliasing issue, `cal_buffer` will *provide storage* for `gcalibration_data`. And `cal_buffer` initialization is a no_op. (not zero initialization). So the code would be 100% language conforming.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. However, I don't see how this is different from what I have, isn't `std::aligned_storage` just a fancy way of saying `unsigned char cal_buffer[sizeof(data_block)]` ? Or is it the reinterpret_cast to the reference that you object to?

Comment: Which got me thinking, wouldn't the most standards compliant way be to declare the storage (either as an array or as `aligned_storage`), and then instead of providing a copy constructor from volatile, provide a constructor from the (volatile) storage type?

Comment: @Timo `aligned storage` is just an array of unsigned char, with appropriate alignment. It is somehow cleaner because the code express the intent: this is a buffer for storage purpose. I think you could use this copy constructor from volatile: `calibration_data(volatile const char*)`. In this case you should also declare the buffer volatile: `volatile aligned_storage<....> buffer`; If this buffer is not declared volatile, you would get an UB because, because the compiler would consider that the buffer contain *indeterminate value*.

Comment: On the other hand, by declaring the buffer volatile, you fall on implementation defined behavior, which in your case would be fine.

Comment: But honestly I suspect the compiler will never treat the initialization as UB, Gcc or Clang tend not to be very clever when array of char are accessed.

Comment: @Timo I am going to change the answer to reflect what I would do. And I think that your solution is fine too. I just don't want to let this answer in this bad state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185619/discussion-between-oliv-and-timo).

Answer (score 2):

The most practical approach would be to lose the `const`. By a strict reading of the standard, `gCalibrationData` shouldn't be *allowed* to be const, since writing to a `const` object -- regardless of who does it -- leads to undefined behavior.

Failing that, though, just define it as `extern const` (and, if necessary to placate the linker, put the non-`extern` definition in its own translation unit. That will get you your const-correctness checking, allow the compiler to, e.g., do hoisting optimizations based on the *initial* values of the calibration data, while still preventing it from making any *specific* assumptions about those values at compile time.

Comment: The whole point of saving in flash is to keep the data across reset/powerdown, so even the initial values are not known at compile time.

Note that writing the flash does not appear to be a write to the variable at all (there is a memory write to the address, but through a `uint16_t *` and preceded by a magical incantation to the flash controller). So I'd still like to argue that the correct type of the variable from language point of view is `const volatile`, i.e. shall never be changed by code, but may nonetheless change on its own.

Comment: So I guess the narrowest view of my problem is that I can't assign (or memcpy) from a `const volatile` without casting away the volatile, which again breaks the code.

Comment: I added a third (still unpalatable) option to the question

Comment: It doesn't need to be `volatile`, since your code is (indirectly) in control of runtime changes to the object. The important part is the `extern`.

Comment: `extern const data_block __attribute__((section (".caldata"))) gCalibrationData{};` doesn't work, it still goes to the error branch.

Comment: That's because you stuck an initializer on there. Should just be `...gCalibrationData;`.

Comment: Still doesn't work (I of course had to add a definition to another .cpp where the initializer is present). I have link time optimizations on (and need to keep them that way), so I'm not surprised the compiler sees the definition there.

Comment: I still think `const volatile` is what I mean, because I want to have an object that I can't change, but when I say read it, I mean read it all the way from memory, even though the compiler hasn't seen anyone touching it.

Comment: I think you're basically stuck, then. Modifying an object which is defined (not just declared) as `const` is UB, with or without the `volatile` qualification. Lose the `const`, hide the definition in a source file, and provide an accessor function which returns a `data_block const*`.

Comment: Even if I did that, wouldn't the compiler still be allowed to analyze my code to see that `gCalibrationData` is never changed and that the pointer returned by the accessor points there, and therefore optimize out the `if`?

Of course we know that it isn't smart enough to do that now, but then I'll have a latent bug waiting for the day the compiler does get that smart...

`const volatile` is the standard in embedded code to access read-only registers, which is exactly the same case, except only that the registers are mapped to primitive types, which you can assign.

Comment: But you might be right that there's no clever way to define the types to make this work.

I think the correct solution in that case would be to write a memcpy with the difference that it takes a volatile argument as the source, and copy byte-by-byte (or say a uint32_t) at a time.

Comment: @Timo After a reset/powerdown, the program will be restarted, and the default initializer executed. Won't you loose the calibration information?

Comment: @oliv no, because the linker places this in a section which is not initialized at startup (it's in flash, so it's assumed to have been initialized when originally writing the program to memory)